# How to browse, an organized, textual list of commands that can be issued to Google Assistant

Tags: google-assistant, google-voice, voice-command, google-voice-actions, voice

I was wondering whether there is any way (my guess, is that this would be almost like an exhaustive dictionary) to go though a textual list of all the Google voice commands you can issue to the Google app or to the Google Assistant app.

Where can I find such a list? Can I find one on the system (perhaps, even within, the Google Assistant app itself, or, alternatively, within a special (related), app on the system)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because of the nature of the Google Assistant, there is no exhaustive list - it tries to determine the meaning in any request and fulfill it as best as it can. That being said, the [Google Support page](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7172842?hl=en) has a good list of basic requests that can be fulfilled. Specifically relevant to an Android phone, they provide this list:

## On Mobile Devices (phones and tablets)

#### Communicate

- Calls: Call Mom. Call Bob on speaker phone. Make a video call
- Duo: Call Mom. Call Living Room Smart Display.

#### On phones only:

- SMS: Text Mike "See you at 5."
- Emails: Send an email.
- WhatsApp: Send a WhatsApp message to Sam.

#### Get around your device

- Change settings: Turn on WiFi. Increase the volume. Decrease the brightness.
- Control your phone: Turn on the flashlight. Take a photo.

Note: Whether Google Assistant can take a photo for you depends on your device
manufacturer.

Find things in your apps: Search for tablets on Amazon. Search for Kanye West on Twitter.

- Find photos: Show my pictures of the beach.

#### Plan your day

- Alarms: Set an alarm for 7 a.m.
- Reservations: Make a reservation for 2 at [restaurant] on Friday.

#### Get things done

- Shopping: Add cereal to my shopping list.
- Donate: Donate $5 to [organization].

Tip: To do two things at once, connect two requests with "and." For example, you could say "Hey Google, turn off the lights and turn on the TV." For now, you can only do two things at once if you use Google Assistant in English.

## Pixel phones (Pixel 4 and above)

#### Take, search & share photos

- "Show me my photos from New York"
- "Take a selfie." Then say "share this with Ryan"
- "Take a picture in 10 seconds"

#### Manage your phone’s settings

- "Turn on the flashlight"
- "Take a screenshot"
- "Turn on Do Not Disturb"
- "Turn on Bluetooth"

#### Make calls or send messages

- "Call Mom"
- “Answer call” or “Reject call”
- "Tell Tina I will be five minutes late"
- "Text Adam, Don’t forget to get milk on your way home"
- In a chat thread, say "Reply, I’m on my way"

#### Open apps

- "Open Translate"
- "Search for yoga classes on YouTube." Then say "Share this with mom"
- "Find hotels in San Diego on Maps"
- "[Artist name] on YouTube Music"
- "Show me emails from Michelle on Gmail"

#### Open websites in Chrome

- Ask Google Assistant to go to a site in the Chrome app.
- "Go to [site name]"
- "Open [site name]"

#### Search in your apps or websites

When you have an app or website open in Chrome, ask Google Assistant to help you complete tasks, like finding a video to watch or searching for a message. It works seamlessly with many apps and we’ll continue improving app integrations over time. For example:

- With the YouTube app open, say "search for cat videos."
- With the Google Photos app open, say "show me New York pictures." Then say "The ones at Central Park."
- With a recipe site open on Chrome, say "Search for chocolate brownies with nuts."
  -With a travel app open, say [hotels in Paris]